# How to use asynchronous Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous

I am using Google maps to get address in mobile application. Code is working fine when there is an internet connection. If not then my app takes 1 minute to load or sometimes it shows an application error. This is due to loading a URL within the script, so I wanted to load my script asynchronously. Can anyone give me some logic to solve my issue, how do I rewrite the below script asynchronously?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true">
function address()
{
              var geocoder ;
              geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
              var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);
              geocoder.geocode({'latLng': latlng}, function(results, status) 
                {                   
                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK)
                 {
                        if (results[0])
                        {
                           var add= results[0].formatted_address ;
                           document.getElementById("location").innerHTML="Location : " + add ;
                        }
                        else 
                        {
                           document.getElementById("location").innerHTML="No Results found " ;
                        }
                }
                 else
                {
                //document.getElementById("location").innerHTML="Geocoder failed due to: " + status;
                //alert("Geocoder failed due to: " + status);               
                }
                });
}
```

Comment: problem for the wait is you application is trying to load `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true`. just comment it out if you are offline.

Comment: There is a gallery of google maps example , you can have a look there .

Comment: But I need to handle both offline and online

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it:

```
jQuery.getScript('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true', address);
```

BTW, `getScript()` is a helper function for `jQuery.ajax()`. if you use the latter you can take more control and set more options, specifically a `timeout` parameter so it does not just spin for ever or the `cache` parameter so that you don't have to look it up all the time

A fiddle that's similar.  Sorry fiddles can't use external resources directly so I have to create a simpler  script request but you can see the callback is referencing the new javascript.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. It looks fine. I need to try now.

Comment: If loading the script asynchronously, the OP will also have to NOT try to use it until it has finished loading, probably by using the completion function on `getScript()`.

Comment: I can't get it. Can you please show one example. Thanks in advance